# How to Conditionally Return a Widget Depending if Some Variable is null in Dart/Flutter Using a Fancy Operator?

Tags: flutter, dart, null, conditional-operator

In Flutter, is there a way to do this:

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (someVar != null) {
      return WidgetA();
    } else {
      return WidgetB();
    }
  }
```

In a nice syntactically sugary way?

I could try this:

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return someVar !?? WidgetA() : WidgetB();
  }
```

... but I know it won't work.

Comment: Ultimately you would need to specify three things: `someVar`, `WidgetA`, and `WidgetB`.  Any sugar from some special operator simply would not provide much convenience over `someVar != null ? WidgetA() : WidgetB()`, so it's not worth adding some new operator for that.  In contrast, operators such as `??` and `?.` avoid needing to type the same things (and avoid evaluating the same expression) multiple times.

Comment: would it work to do: someVar ?? WidgetB() : WidgetA() ? (if someVar IS null, then show B, otherwise A).

Comment: No, that's not how `??` works, and `:` is part of the `?:` conditional/ternary operator.  And again, the only thing you're trying to save is having to type `== null` (or `!= null`).  That's really not much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You wrote:

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    someVar !?? WidgetA() : WidgetB();
  }
```

It should be `?` and `:` for the ternary operator. And in case you don't want to show anything, you can use an empty `SizedBox`.

So it could be something like:

```
Container(
  child: _hasName ? Text(name) : SizedBox(),
)
```

Or if you are writing the build method, don't forget to use the `return` keyword:

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return someVar ? WidgetA() : WidgetB();
  }
```

Comment: Yes, but I am checking whether a variable (not necessarily of bool type) is null or not.

Comment: oh, you mean like, `return someVar != null ? WidgetA() : WidgetB()`?